Как заставить Jest импортировать модули из другого места?
Я использую библиотеку Swiper в своем React компоненте. По одной очень важной причине все модули проекта должны обязательно поддерживать import и require, к сожалению Swiper поддерживает только import и мне приходится подключать его вот так:

let SwiperWrapper: any = null;
let SwiperSlide: any = null;
let SwiperNavigation: any = null;
let SwiperPagination: any = null;
let SwiperAutoplay: any = null;

  SwiperWrapper = require('swiper/react').Swiper;
  SwiperSlide = require('swiper/react').SwiperSlide;
  SwiperNavigation = require('swiper').Navigation;
  SwiperPagination = require('swiper').Pagination;
  SwiperAutoplay = require('swiper').Autoplay;

export { SwiperWrapper, SwiperSlide, SwiperNavigation, SwiperPagination, SwiperAutoplay };

Из-за такого подключения тесты в Jest падают с ошибкой:
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:                                                     ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      11 |
      12 
    > 13 |   SwiperWrapper = require('swiper/react').Swiper;
         |                   ^
      14 |   SwiperSlide = require('swiper/react').SwiperSlide;
      15 |   SwiperNavigation = require('swiper').Navigation;
      16 |   SwiperPagination = require('swiper').Pagination;

Как заставить Jest во время тестов брать Swiper не через require, а через import?

В папке с моками создай мок.

В данный момент есть такие моки,
export const Swiper = () => null;
export const SwiperSlide = () => null;
export const Navigation = {};
export const Pagination = {};
export const Autoplay = {};

но для написания качественных тестов нужны именно настоящие модули
